# How to draw a moving point with time?

Tags: graphics

I am new to Mathematica. Try to draw a point moving with time. Like at t=0, a point is at p1(coordinates are random numbers); at t=1, this point is at p2. And there is always ONE point on the graph. Below is my code, xy[t_] is the point coordinate at time t in a 2D region.

I have two problems here,

1). Points can be out of this region. How to fix it?

2). All the points are shown on a same graph, how to show only one point at a certain time t?

Any help? Thank you.

```
xy[t_]=Module[{t},
         Table[
             If[t<1,{x[0]=0,y[0]=RandomReal[{-1,1}]},
                    {x[t]=RandomReal[{0,1}],y[t]=RandomReal[{-1,1}]}],{t,0,10}]]

Animate[Graphics[{Red,PointSize[0.05],Point[xy[t]]},
  AxesLabel->{"x","y"},
  PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,10}}],{t,0,10}]
```

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your creation of `xy[t_]=...` is not a good idea in the sense that `xy[anything]` produces a static table.

Try

```
xyPointList = 
 Module[{t}, 
  Table[If[t < 1, {x[0] = 0, 
     y[0] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x[t] = 
      x[t - 1] + RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
     y[t] = y[t - 1] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}], {t, 0, 10}]]

(* {{0, 0.0251049}, {0.211352, 0.0367706}, {0.489274, 
  0.7281}, {1.39872, 0.538182}, {1.68534, 1.26225}, {2.18648, 
  1.66184}, {2.4956, 2.65684}, {2.69291, 1.87413}, {3.20496, 
  1.26491}, {3.30305, 2.02537}, {4.0114, 2.23029}} *)
```

Next use `Map` to produce a list of red points. I have adjusted the `PlotRange` so your points do not go off scale.

```
xyGraphicsList = 
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[#]}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 10}, {-3, 3}}] & /@ xyPointList;
```

Finally, use `ListAnimate` rather than `Animate`.

```
ListAnimate[xyList]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need and it's very clear. Thanks Again. BTW, here is only one point moving, if I want to add more points (like 10 points) moving, how to make it work? I am trying to use     xyPointList[n_] where n=10, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. You may have some work to do to place the expressions in the proper format for `ListAnimate` and to say have different colors for the different groups of points, but in principle what you have is great.

Answer (score 4):

I am precomputing an [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) of random numbers from 0 to 1 for `x` and -1 to 1 for `y` that will be the displacements. To that I [`Prepend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prepend.html) `{0,0}` to define a fixed initial position. Then I [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) that list for a successive accumulated totals of elements. Then use [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) so the function is also defined at any arbitrary  position between points.

```
xy = Interpolation[
   Accumulate[
    Prepend[
     Array[{RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}]} &, 100],
     {0, 0}
     ]]
   , InterpolationOrder -> 1
   ];
```

Then the trajectory is like this

```
Plot[xy[t], {t, 0, 50}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now for the animation notice the `{t, xy[t]}` coordinates.

```
Animate[Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[{t, xy[t]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {-5, 5}}], {t, 0, 
  50}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The point moves very smoothly and beautiful. But a little confused about  " Array ", Thank you for giving me a chance to learn it and Mma.